# Google Maps not loaded in jMeter through Mozilla Firefox

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Google Maps is unable to view on Firefox using jMeter.

I was performing load testing in which forms are being loaded but Google Maps was not being loaded in Firefox. I was able to perform the same stuff in Chrome using blazemeter.

How can I do the same thing in Firefox as there is no help for the same. It does not show any errors.

Comment: Please provide more information of what you are looking for, what have you tried and what errors are you getting.

Comment: I was performing load testing in which forms are being loaded but google map was not being loaded in firefox but I was able to perform the same stuff in chrome using blazemeter.How can i do the same thing in firefox as there is no help for the same.With respect to errors it does not show any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Leave load testing of Google Maps to Google test engineers (unless you're one of them) and focus solely on your application features. Google Maps isn't something you can control, if API call works slowly or doesn't work - you won't be able to do anything with it.

So

1. **During recording**: filter out Google Maps (and any other "external" domains) via "URL Patterns To Exclude" input of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
2. **During test execution:** do the same for any embedded resources (scripts, images, styles, etc.) using [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) and "URLS must match" input.

Example regular expression to filter out all Google domains will look like:

```
^((?!google).)*$
```

See [Excluding Domains from the Load Test](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1903905-excluding-domains-from-the-load-test) guide for more detailed explanation

Comment: I tried that before but google maps are the part of our application so excluding them will impact on performance in future course of time.